# Swift4 addTarget at UIButton doesnt work in UIView

Tags: swift, uibutton, subview, addtarget

I programmatically created an UIButton and added it to a subview. AddTarget doesnt work there though. AddTarget only works if I add the button to the mainview.

```
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

instead of

```
ViewSystem.addSubview(button)
```

Doesnt anyone know why?

Here is the fullcode:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var ViewSystem = UIView()
@objc func TestPressed(sender: UIButton?) {Test.text=String((sender?.tag)!)

func ButtonCreate () {

    let button = UIButton()
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 70, height: 70)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TestPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    button.tag=5
    ViewSystem.addSubview(button)

    self.view.addSubview(ViewSystem)
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

Comment: try ViewSystem.clipsToBounds = true. and i am sure you won't able to see your button

Comment: You didn't specify the frame of `ViewSystem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give frame to your ViewSystem. and ViewSystem's height width should be greater than button's X and Y.

```
    var ViewSystem = UIView()
ViewSystem.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 70, height: 70)

@objc func TestPressed(sender: UIButton?) {Test.text=String((sender?.tag)!)

func ButtonCreate () {

    let button = UIButton()
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 70)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TestPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    button.tag=5
    ViewSystem.addSubview(button)

    self.view.addSubview(ViewSystem)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This happening because you are set your button frame graterthen your view that's why  your button not tapped.

you are not set your view frame and then how you can you set your button inside your view.

Here I update your   **ButtonCreate ()**  function code it's working nicely.

```
func ButtonCreate () {
            ViewSystem.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 200, height: 70)
            ViewSystem.backgroundColor = .blue
            let button = UIButton()
            button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 70)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TestPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            button.tag = 5
            ViewSystem.clipsToBounds = false
            ViewSystem.addSubview(button)

            self.view.addSubview(ViewSystem)
        }
```

I hope it's helpfull for you and save your time

Comment: helped a lot, thanks! I just accepted the other answer cause it was posted earlier. Sadly I cannot accept both

Comment: I appriciate your replay

Comment: I upvoted. This was by far the best and easiest answer to the same problem which I had.